Dataset Not found: Dataset my-test:kronos was not found in location US
I am trying to create a scheduled query that deletes some rows first and then creates a union.  Here is the code
declare min_date date;

set min_date = (select min(parse_date("%m/%d/%Y", trim(work_date))) 
from `my-test.kronos.time_data_28`);

delete from `my-test.kronos.time_data`
where parse_date("%m/%d/%Y", trim(work_date)) >= min_date;

 
select name, WorkDate, Hours, emp_name, project_status from `my-test.kronos.time_data`

union all  
select name, WorkDate, Hours, emp_name, project_status 
from `my-test.kronos.time_data_14`

union all  
select name, WorkDate, Hours, emp_name, project_status 
from `my-test.kronos.time_data_28

When I run this code in a query studio it runs fine. But if I try to set a scheduled query with it, I get Not found: Dataset my_test:kronos was not found in location US.
Is there a way I can create a scheduled query using this code block?

Do these link1  and link2 help you?

Hi @Rashida, has your issue been resolved after changing the scheduled query location to us-central1?
